# Webpack Error when running "gulp serve" for basic Hello World webpart

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

I am getting the following error when running  "gulp serve" command after scaffolding the basic Hello World web-part project. I have installed the latest versions of Node LTS v6.9.5 and TypeScript 2.1.6 as showing in the image below:

[image: webpack error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like an issue with your path having a ! in it.  Can you start with a directory called SPFX, rather than !SPFX?

Comment: You are 100% correct and it did the trick. Thanks a lot Pat for your prompt response. Is this a restriction or bug to get fixed?